# document.getElementByClassName not working but document.getElementById works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the html with 2 div's I have. I want to set the separate border for each div. When I use method separate ID for both div, it works but when I use class it doesn't. How can I make it work using same class name for multiple div to put border around.

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {

    document.getElementByClassName("myDiv").style.border = "thin solid #0000FF";

}

</script>




<style type="text/css">
 .myDiv {

  border: "thick solid #0000FF;"
 }
</style>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1><strong style="color: #ff0000;">Mechannics</strong></h1>
<div>
<div class="rawal">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="myDiv" style="padding: 8px;">
<p><span style="color: #00bcf4;"><strong>1) <u>Units of Measurement</u></strong></span></p>
<p><strong><em>@ K</em></strong><em>ing &nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ector&nbsp; <strong>D</strong>ied &nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ysteriously&nbsp;<strong>D</strong>rinking&nbsp;</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;K</strong>ilo&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ecto&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>D</strong>eka &nbsp;<strong>M</strong>eter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>D</strong>eci&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><em>C</em></strong><em>hoklate&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ilk</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>C</strong>enti&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Milli</span>
<p>&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;</p>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div class="myDiv">

<p><span style="color: #00bcf4;"><strong><u>2) Tens ' Multipliers</u></strong></span></p>
<p><strong><em>@ D</em></strong><em>esi&nbsp;</em>&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong><em>H</em></strong><em>ero</em>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><em>K</em></strong><em>illed&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ega&nbsp;<strong>G</strong>igantic&nbsp;<strong>T</strong>errorists</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; D</strong>ekka&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ecto &nbsp;<strong>K</strong>ilo&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ega&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>G</strong>iga&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>T</strong>era</span>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>1</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>2</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>3</sup>&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>6</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>9</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>12</sup></p>
<p>&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;</p>

</div>
```

and here is the image I want to get which I get when I use separate Id for both
and use a function

```
 document.getElementById("myDiv").style.border = "thin solid #0000FF";


document.getElementById("myDivv").style.border = "thin solid #0000FF";
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ENx.jpg)

Comment: There is no such thing as `getElementByClassName`. Either use `getElementsByClassName` instead, or even better, avoid HTMLCollections altogether, and use `querySelectorAll` instead (which returns a static NodeList, which is directly iterable over on modern browsers)

Comment: @CertainPerformance getElementsByClassName also doesn't not work.

Comment: @BirNepali - I bet you're using it wrong - expecting a single node?

Comment: you'd want `document.getElemenstByClassName("myDiv")[0].style.border` - because that's how you use HTMLCollections/NodeLists

Comment: @JaromandaX https://jsfiddle.net/m4jv0jrm/ It does indeed return an HTMLCollection, just like all the `getElementsBy*` methods.

Comment: lol, I fat fingered (I never know what returns what) ... and tested `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementsByClassName` - mea culpa :p (note, not ALL `getElementsBy*` )

Comment: @JaromandaX, It only works  for the first div and the rest div remains same...so what's the point of using class instead of ID.I want to do same style to multple div's here..not just first one...is there any better alternative.

Comment: oh, so you want it to work on more ... then ***iterate*** through the HTMLCollection (for loop works well for beginners)

Comment: any example will be best..and one question instead of using script when I use <div class="myDiv" style="padding: 8px; border: 2px;border-color: red;"> why doesn't it work??

Comment: or `Array.from(document.getElementByClassName("myDiv")).forEach(e => e.style.border = "thin solid #0000FF");` for the adventurous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** of all it is `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName` missing **s**

**Secondly** it returns array-like object of all child so you have to use loop to apply css styles all of its child.

**Advice:** [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is more useful when you want to use more complex selectors and has great browser compatibility

So, you can try with [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to Return an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names and loop through them to apply your css style like this.

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
 
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv');
  for(i=0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    cols[i].style.border='thin solid #0000FF';
    linebreak = document.createElement("br");
    cols[i].after(linebreak);
  }
}

</script>

<style type="text/css">
 .myDiv {
  border: "thick solid #0000FF;"
 }
</style>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1><strong style="color: #ff0000;">Mechannics</strong></h1>
<div>
<div class="rawal">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="myDiv" style="padding: 8px;">
<p><span style="color: #00bcf4;"><strong>1) <u>Units of Measurement</u></strong></span></p>
<p><strong><em>@ K</em></strong><em>ing &nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ector&nbsp; <strong>D</strong>ied &nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ysteriously&nbsp;<strong>D</strong>rinking&nbsp;</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp;K</strong>ilo&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ecto&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong>D</strong>eka &nbsp;<strong>M</strong>eter&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>D</strong>eci&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><strong><em>C</em></strong><em>hoklate&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ilk</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>C</strong>enti&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Milli</span>
<p>&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;</p>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">
<p><span style="color: #00bcf4;"><strong><u>2) Tens ' Multipliers</u></strong></span></p>
<p><strong><em>@ D</em></strong><em>esi&nbsp;</em>&nbsp; &nbsp;<strong><em>H</em></strong><em>ero</em>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><em>K</em></strong><em>illed&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ega&nbsp;<strong>G</strong>igantic&nbsp;<strong>T</strong>errorists</em></p>
<span style="color: #0000ff;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; D</strong>ekka&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>H</strong>ecto &nbsp;<strong>K</strong>ilo&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>M</strong>ega&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>G</strong>iga&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>T</strong>era</span>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>1</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>2</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>3</sup>&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>6</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<sup>9</sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;10<sup>12</sup></p>
<p>&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;&hellip;</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Ok I'll make you answer accepted from my another account as I have less reputation here...By the way HOw can I use <br> tag here..I added the line   cols[i].createElement("BR"); inside function but it didn't worked.

Comment: try like this `linebreak = document.createElement("br");
cols[i].appendChild(linebreak);`

Comment: It give me this result https://ibb.co/cB8bjS instead I want to separate the each box as give in above image in question.

Comment: @BirNepali see my edited answer now. I've used `after()` method and removed literal <br> tags from your html.Run the snipped and see it is working as per your requirement now. Feel free to up-vote and accept my answer now :)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i need.

Comment: I already voted for you from my another account..I'll vote again once I get enough reputation from this account

Answer (score 1):

You miss the "s" in the name of the function, it's `getElementsByClassName`but if you will use `getElementById` it's without the "s".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "document.getElementByClassName" - what you're after is document.getElement**s**ByClassName. It returns all the elements as an Array that match that class name. Then you just need to pick the one you want from the array.

See the documentation for it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")[0]` , `document.getElementsByClassName("myDiv")[1]` etc

Comment: it actually returns an HTMLCollection which is like an array except noniterable. If you wrap the call in `Array.from()` then you can iterate over it

Comment: Better yet, use `querySelectorAll` which returns a NodeList which *is* directly iterable on modern browsers.